# Using express.json instead of express.bodyparser

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm building a simple REST API and I only want to accept JSON input.

I am opting to use `app.use(express.json({strict: true}));`  instead of `app.use(express.bodyParser());`.

I am passing `strict: true` thinking that that would add a layer of security against invalid json. Anyone else doing anything similar? Looking for suggestions from someone who was experience with this setup.

Comment: it's `strict` by default. you don't need to set it as true.

Comment: In post request if u want to get the post value means.you should add this middleware -app.use(express.bodyParser());.

Comment: I don't think that is true @sachin. Mine is working. Body parser is a collection of `app.use(connect.json());
app.use(connect.urlencoded());
app.use(connect.multipart());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, since you are potentially reducing the attack area on your app. But, I'm not sure there's any evidence that using bodyParser (which would allow some malformed JSON, as well as url-encoded and multipart-form encoded data as well) would be any meaningful risk.

You can see exactly what `strict: true` means here:

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/json.html

```
if (strict && '{' != buf[0] && '[' != buf[0]) return next(utils.error(400, 'invalid json'));
```

It just ensures that the JSON starts with a { or a [. You're still relying on Google not to have screwed up their JSON.parse implementation in V8 the way Rails did with YAML, which I think is a relatively safe bet.

Comment: Hey....just as an addition to this. Have a look at http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html